# How do i make the image show up on a html file with XAMPP?

Tags: html, xampp

I've tried

```
<img src = 'name.png'/>
```

and

```
<img src = 'localhost:1234/name.png'/>
```

and others but the image doesn't appear on the website

Comment: It is unclear what you ask. What do you actually mean by "link images to a .html"?

Comment: Just use `<img src="name of the image.jpeg" />`

Comment: @DaanMeijer And that "links to a .html"?

Comment: @arkascha Well, it links to the image in the .html document. That was my interpretation of the question. Although I upvoted your comment, because as it stands, the question is quite unclear.

Comment: By link images i mean using the <img src=>, I've tried <img src='name.jpg'/>, in all of the combinations of the location that i could think of but it doesn't show up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

depends where your image is located

if you have in the root folder a folder called image then you can display the image with the img tag

```
<img src="image/yourimagehere.jpg" alt="" >
```

if is in the root folder then just simply use it

```
<img src="yourimagehere.jpg" alt="" >
```

if you just need to access the image then use the anchor tag

```
<a href="pathToYourImage/image.png">image or whaever you want</a>
```

Comment: You are right, but i don't know why it doesn't show up, i have the image in This PC/OS(C:)/xampp/htdocs but i don't know what the img src would be, i tried /htdocs/name.png and /This PC/OS(C:)/xampp/htdocs.png and name.png

Comment: Wait it works by just putting name.png, i think it was something else

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

```
<a href="nameofpage.html"><img src="nameofimg.jpg"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want the image to appear in your page use:

```
<img src="nameOfImage.jpeg" />
```

If you want just a link to it use (the image will not appear in the page):

```
<a href="nameOfImage.jpeg"></a>
```

if you want them both (a clickable image):

```
<a href="nameOfImage.jpeg"><img src="nameOfImage.jpeg" /></a>
```